# d3 importing csv file to array

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to import a .csv file using the d3.csv() method. Here is my code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
```

What I thought I would get is an array containing objects, each representing a line of my .csv file (of which there are 50). What I'm *actually* getting, though, is a series of independent objects. That is, the function has logged 50 objects to my console, *not* one array containing 50 objects. Am I misunderstanding this method? If so, how can I get such an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In d3 **v5** the API for fetching data has changed quite a bit, which became necessary as the underlying workings have switched from using `XMLHttpRequest` to the Fetch API. In prior versions of D3 up to v4 your code would have behaved as you expected printing the single resulting array. The new API for [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#csv), however, look like this:

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#csv) d3.**csv**(*input*[, *init*][, *row*]) [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/src/dsv.js)

Further down the docs provide an [explanation](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#dsv) for your observation:

> If only one of *init* and *row* is specified, it is interpreted as the *row* conversion function if it is a function, and otherwise an init object.

In your code the second argument to `d3.csv()` is a function and is, thus, interpreted as the row conversion function. Because the row conversion function is executed for every single row in your input file you see each object printed individually instead of the whole array at once.

Since `d3.csv()` returns a Promise the correct usage would be like this:

```
d3.csv("data.csv")
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Here `data` refers to the entire array of objects.